Each group of three among $n$ people conspire against someone else. Then someone has $\ge\sqrt[3]{(n - 1)(n - 2)}$ conspirators.
I stumbled onto this problem from the Italian 2005 IMO TST  while just doing different Combinatorics problems. The problem statement:

A stage course is attended by $n \geq 4$ students. The day before the final exam, each group of three students conspire against another student to throw him/her out of the exam. Prove that there is a student against whom there are at least $\sqrt[3]{(n - 1)(n - 2)}$ conspirators.

Now, there are a total of $\binom{n}{3}$ triplets of students. If they each conspire against a single person, there would be a total of $3\binom{n}{3}$ conspiracies against people. The average of this divided over $n$ students is:
$$ \frac{3}{n}\binom{n}{3} = \frac{3}{n}\cdot\frac{n(n - 1)(n - 2)}{6} = \frac{(n - 1)(n - 2)}{2}$$
So at least one student must have more than $(n - 1)(n - 2)/2$ conspirators. Since $x/2 > \sqrt[3]{x}$ in the region $x \in [6, \infty)$, this seemingly solves the problem? This solution seems quite suspicious, though, as it is too simple for a TST problem. Is there an issue with my solution?

How can the number of conspiracies that exist exceed $n \choose 3$, the number of sets of conspirators?

You're double-counting the conspirators. Note in particular that a student cannot have more than $n+1$ conspirators. You need to take the size of the set, not the size of the multi-set.

@PaulTanenbaum I believe OP is counting pairs of "conspirator in triplet, student", of which there are $ 3 \times { n \choose 3 } $ of them.

Not directly relevant to the question, but what is suspicious to me is rather the question 2 of the first day.

Let there be a bipartite graph with parts $U$ and $V$, where $U$ contains $\binom{n}{3}$ vertices (the groups), and $V$ contains $n$ vertices (the people). Then there is an edge in the graph if and only if the group in $U$ conspires against the person in $V$.
We see by the pigeonhole principle that there must be a vertex in $V$ with degree at least $$\left\lceil \frac{\binom{n}{3}}{n}\right\rceil =  \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{6}.$$
The question is now, what is the minimum number of distinct people that come from the $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{6}$ groups of $3$?
After a bit of scratch work, we see that $1$ group has to give $3$ distinct people, $2$ groups give at least $1$ new person. However, you can take $3$ groups that give only $4$ people by selecting a group from within the union of the groups that you have already chosen. What happens is, if you have $\binom{k}{3}$ groups with $k \leq n$, then the number of distinct people formed by these groups is minimum $k$, but if you have $\binom{k}{3} < x \leq \binom{k+1}{3}$ groups, then the minimum is $k+1$ (just select from existing groups).
It is easy to show $$
\binom{
\left\lceil
((n-1)(n-2))^{\frac{1}{3}}
\right\rceil}{3} 
< \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{6} 
\leq \binom{
\left\lceil((n-1)(n-2))^{\frac{1}{3}}
\right\rceil + 1}{3}
$$ from which the claim follows. I will just show the lower bound. The upper bound is easier.
Let $x = (n - 1)(n - 2)$ and $ k = \lceil x^{1/3} \rceil $. We want to show that $k(k-1)(k-2) < x$.
Then we have $k - 1 < x^{1/3} \leq k$ and $$ k(k - 1)(k - 2) = k(k^2 - 3k + 2) = k^3 - 3k^2 + 2k.$$ But since $x > (k - 1)^3 = k^3 - 3k^2 + 3k - 1$ we have $x > k(k-1)(k-2)$ and we're done. The upper bound is similar.

Thank you, this checks out. Do we need the upper bound? Isn't it enough to have $\binom{k}{3} < x$ with minimum greater than $k$?

@pjq42 yes of course you need to have the maximum, this is explained in the "scratch work" paragraph
